# Getting error ever since I updated Terraform module

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I updated my Terraform version and the eks module. Now I am getting a-lot of errors while running the terraform script (which was running fine previously). Some of them I fixed.

```
    Error: Invalid value for module argument

  on eks.tf line 27, in module "eks":
  27:   map_roles = [
  28:      {
  29:       role_arn = "${format("arn:aws:iam::%s:role/admin", var.target_account_id)}"
  30:       username = "${format("%s-admin", var.name)}"
  31:       group    = ["system:masters"]
  32:      },
  33:    ]

The given value is not suitable for child module variable "map_roles" defined
at
.terraform/modules/eks/terraform-aws-modules-terraform-aws-eks-1be1a02/variables.tf:63,1-21:
element 0: attributes "groups" and "rolearn" are required.


Error: Unsupported block type

  on provider.tf line 30, in data "terraform_remote_state" "state":
  30:   config {

Blocks of type "config" are not expected here. Did you mean to define argument
"config"? If so, use the equals sign to assign it a value.
```

I believe they have removed the **map_accounts_count and map_roles_count** variables.

Documentation is not that clear. I even checked on the release notes.

below is my eks.tf

```
module "eks" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws"
  version = "6.0.2"

  cluster_name = "${var.name}"
  subnets      = ["${module.vpc.private_subnets}"]
  vpc_id       = "${module.vpc.vpc_id}"
  cluster_version = "${var.cluster_version}"

  kubeconfig_aws_authenticator_additional_args = ["-r", "arn:aws:iam::${var.target_account_id}:role/terraform"]

  worker_groups = [
    {
      instance_type        = "${var.eks_instance_type}"
      asg_desired_capacity = "${var.eks_asg_desired_capacity}"
      asg_max_size         = "${var.eks_asg_max_size}"
      key_name             = "${var.key_name}"
    },
  ]


  map_accounts = ["${var.target_account_id}"]
  map_roles = [
     {
      role_arn = "${format("arn:aws:iam::%s:role/admin", var.target_account_id)}"
      username = "${format("%s-admin", var.name)}"
      group    = ["system:masters"]
     },
   ]


  #map_accounts_count = "1"
  #map_roles_count    = "1"

  write_kubeconfig      = "false"
  write_aws_auth_config = "false"
}

resource "local_file" "kubeconfig" {
  content  = "${module.eks.kubeconfig}"
  filename = "./.kube_config.yaml"
}
```

Comment: What version did you upgrade to and from? That will help.

Comment: @Jamie
terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws: 2.2.0 to 6.0.2
terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws: 1.53.0 to 2.17.0
terraform: 0.10 to 0.12.12

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks/blob/v6.0.2/variables.tf#L63-L71 and the error you need to update:

- `group` to `groups`
- `role_arn` to `rolearn`

In addition to that you need to update maps to use assignment with `=` like the docs suggest at https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/terraform/d/remote_state.html. Your remote state config (and possibly other maps) need to look like:

```
map = {
  data = "string"
}
```

Instead of

```
map {
  data = "string"
}
```

Comment: thanks for pointing out issue. I changed a lot of syntax issue but now getting this 

Get http://localhost/apis/rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1/clusterrolebindings/tiller: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:80: connect: connection refused

Get http://localhost/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/serviceaccounts/tiller: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:80: connect: connection refused